# Unity textures not same that in blender

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

When I import models with their textures from blender to unity, the texture is normal in blender but when i add it to the model in unity it turns "ugly". [Blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqs6z.png) [Unity: (Texture added to one part of the mesh.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIWSH.png)

I tried to import the models as obj but that did nothing. I tried to check if the material had some settings and that didnt work. I need help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try UV unwrapping the model in blender.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).